# SQL order and limit then order the limited results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select dates by DESC and limit to the last 3 then I need to basically flip the last 3 results so they order by ASC

Any help would be grateful I am using postgresql

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT column_list
    FROM tableX
    ORDER BY dates DESC
    LIMIT 3
  ) AS tmp
ORDER BY dates ASC ;
```